# How can I filter an object of all properties that are objects?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a copy of an object that only includes the properties that are not objects. But the child objects get copied along with it.

```
var testObject = {
  stringProperty: "hi",
  intProperty: 4,
  objectProperty: {},
  nullProperty: null
};

console.log(removeChildObjects(testObject));

function removeChildObjects(object) {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);
  var newObject = {};
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, object[key], typeof object[key]);
    if (typeof object[key] != "object") {
      newObject[key] = object[key];
    }
  });
  return object;
}
```

Also check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/uss94sc3/1/

Comment: Note that arrays are objects, do you want to remove them, too?

Comment: Did you trace through your program with a debugger? Pay special attention to the `return` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the same object that passed:

```
return object;
```

You should return `newObject`

```
return newObject;
```

Comment: Double facepalm!! Thanks.

Comment: @Person93 It's OK :) be careful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strictly filter out object properties (keeping `null` and `undefined` properties), then you cannot rely on the broken `typeof` unary operator.

```
typeof null
// "object"
```

You can either change your code to:

```
function removeChildObjects(object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    var newObject = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        if (typeof object[key] != "object" || object[key] == null) {
            newObject[key] = object[key];
        }
    });
    return newObject;
}
```

or more succinctly with underscore:

```
function removeChildObjects(object) {
    return _.omit(object, _.isObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `return object;` with `return newObject;`. It will work a lot better!

https://jsfiddle.net/w3urvpjq/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```js
var testObject = {
                  stringProperty: "hi",
                     intProperty: 4,
                  objectProperty: {},
                    nullProperty: null
                 };
var filterPrimitive = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((p,k) => {typeof o[k] != "object" && (p[k] = o[k]); return p},{});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filterPrimitive(testObject),null,2) + "</pre>");
```